# Series calculation

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

I have some random integers like

```
99 20 30 1 100 400 5 10
```

I have to find a sum from any combination of these integers that is closest(equal or more but not less) to a given number like

```
183
```

what is the fastest and accurate way of doing this?

Comment: Sound a lot like homework to anybody else?

Comment: this is going to be horribly ugly. out of curiosity why do u need this>?

Comment: @justin what business is it of yours what he needs it for? and if it is homework does that mean u shouldnt help him?

Comment: @JOE: It means the answer will differ. Less fish giving, more fishing teaching.

Comment: haha) no. this is only a part of a big problem I need to solve for an application. my intention is to find the fastest way of solving this bit.

Comment: @Joe - Dude. Chill. The fact that it is homework simply changes the kind of answer the OP gets. Before answering homework questions we usually like to see some sort of attempt first. Even then, the answer usually helps point the OP to the correct answer but let them figure out the final solution for themselves instead of simply giving them the answer.

Comment: @Joe Helping people cheat on homework is generally discouraged. The proper way to ask a question which is homework, is to first specify that it is homework, and secondly provide an example of what you've tried.

Comment: @JOE: Every homework should be tagged accordingly. We are here to teach people how to fish; Not to do their homeworks for them. If tagged properly, we will proceed to point the OP in the right direction. For more information over SO homework policies, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework.

Comment: @bruno are you imposing moral judgement here?

Comment: @JOE: Are you responding to the right commenter? Your comment seems pretty random.

Comment: well come on guys! this is not a home work for god sake!! I personally don't do a lot of maths. but one of my project requires this kind of wired calculation. Please share if you know!

Comment: @Emon - How many integers are you expecting as input? Since this appears to be NP-Complete, the best solution will depend upon the size of the input.

Comment: Just for the record, he *can't* tag it as homework because the question has five tags already. But then again, he did already say it wasn't homework.

Comment: @Emon - If your numbers are not really big, see my answer - it has better complexity than bruteforce

Comment: @Emon - I updated my answer. Feel free to ask any questions about it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your numbers are small, you can use a simple [Dynamic Programming(DP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) technique. Don't let this name scare you. The technique is fairly understandable. Basically you break the larger problem into subproblems.

Here we define the problem to be `can[number]`. If the `number` can be constructed from the integers in your file, then `can[number]` is `true`, otherwise it is `false`. It is obvious that `0` is constructable by not using any numbers at all, so `can[0]` is `true`. Now you try to use every number from the input file. We try to see if the sum `j` is achievable. If an `already achieved sum + current number we try == j`, then `j` is clearly achievable. If you want to keep track of what numbers made a particular sum, use an additional `prev` array, which stores the last used number to make the sum. See the code below for an implementation of this idea:

```
int UPPER_BOUND = number1 + number2 + ... + numbern //The largest number you can construct
bool can[UPPER_BOUND + 1]; //can[number] is true if number can be constructed
can[0] = true; //0 is achievable always by not using any number

int prev[UPPER_BOUND + 1]; //prev[number] is the last number used to achieve sum "number"
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) //Try to use every number(numbers[i]) from the input file
{
   for (int j = UPPER_BOUND; j >= 1; j--) //Try to see if j is an achievable sum
   {
      if (can[j]) continue; //It is already an achieved sum, so go to the next j

      if (j - numbers[i] >= 0 && can[j - numbers[i]]) //If an (already achievable sum) + (numbers[i]) == j, then j is obviously achievable
      {
          can[j] = true;
          prev[j] = numbers[i]; //To achieve j we used numbers[i]
      } 
   }
}

int CLOSEST_SUM = -1;
for (int i = SUM; i <= UPPER_BOUND; i++)
   if (can[i])
   {
       //the closest number to SUM(larger than SUM) is i
       CLOSEST_SUM = i;
       break; 
   }

int currentSum = CLOSEST_SUM;    
do
{
    int usedNumber = prev[currentSum];
    Console.WriteLine(usedNumber);

    currentSum -= usedNumber;
} while (currentSum > 0);
```

Comment: @Petar - as I've mentioned I'm not a math guy, it took me a bit of time to understood your solution. just to be complete clear, could you please tell me what if i want to achieve the sum in minimum but not less[ based on edited question]? how would you change the algorithm?

Comment: and also how to keep the record which number has given the achieved sum?

Comment: @Peter - this is fantastic. the only thing is the CLOSEST_SUM loop should be other way around: for (int i = SUM; i < UPPER_BOUND; i++)

Comment: @lternity - Why should it matter? He wants to find one solution, not all:)

Comment: @Petar - It just made me interested and I liked your way of solving!

Comment: @lternity - Oh, you are Emon the original poster. It seems you changed your handle:) Sorry for not recognizing.

Comment: @lternity - Feel free to ask anything you don't understand:)

Comment: no prob Petar:) so where and how would you add the logic. and is this a good solution for large set of numbers? sorry to bomb you with questions:-(

Comment: The solution has complexity `N * sum of numbers`. If the numbers are 1000 for example and every number is from 0 to 1000, the program will run for about `1` second I guess. The solution is better when the numbers aren't large(not N, but the numbers). For what additional logic are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of the SUBSET-SUM problem, and is also NP-Hard like SUBSET-SUM.

But if the numbers involved are small, pseudo-polynomial time algorithms exist. Check out:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Ok More details.

The following problem:

> Given an array of integers, and integers a,b, is there
>   some subset whose sum lies in the
>   interval [a,b] is NP-Hard.

This is so because we can solve subset-sum by choosing a=b=0.

Now this problem easily reduces to your problem and so your problem is NP-Hard too.

Now you can use the polynomial time approximation algorithm mentioned in the wiki link above.

Given an array of N integers, a target S and an approximation threshold c,

there is a polynomial time approximation algorithm (involving 1/c) which tells if there is a subset sum in the interval [(1-c)S, S].

You can use this repeatedly (by some form of binary search) to find the best approximation to S you need. Note you can also use this on intervals of the from [S, (1+c)S], while the knapsack will only give you a solution <= S.

Of course there might be better algorithms, in fact I can bet on it. There should be plenty of literature on the web. Some search terms you can use: approximation algorithms for subset-sum, pseudo-polynomial time algorithms, dynamic programming algorithm etc.

Comment: Actually, this variant isn't NP-Complete. Subset sum is because its solution is easily checked (sum = target ? pass : fail). This is not, as the solution cannot be checked in polynomial time (since you have to perform the same problem solving to see if you can find a *better* answer. The only time this wouldn't be the case is when the solution *is* the target)

Comment: @Moron: The problem, as stated, is looking for the *maximum* sum among the available integers that is less than the target value. In the general case, that means we must assume that the solution < target. In order to verify the solution, you must perform the same NP-hard search for a sum to see if there is a "better" (greater but still <= target) match. Because of that, solution is NP-hard and thus the algorithm is not NP-C.

Comment: @Moron: Actually, it appears that the problem is looking for the *closest* match (which implies that > target is acceptable), but that doesn't change the substance of my previous comment; trying to find a "closer" match is still NP-hard.

Comment: @Adam: The decision problem: is there a sum in the range [S-c, S+c] is in NP (and NP-Hard too). Take c =1, 2, 2^2, .., 2^(log S), etc and you are done. There are multiple characterizations of NP, not just based on certificates. Once you find a sum in a range, you can binary search out the closest (which still keeps it polynomial).

Comment: @Moron: A "better" solution could be an entirely different set of numbers from the solution being checked. You can't simply perform a linear search out from each member to see if there exists a better substitution, as *all* of the members could be wrong.

Comment: @Adam: Again: The P time checkability of a certificate is not the only characterization of NP. For instance, your logic can be applied to the knapsack problem too, which is _known_ to be NP-Complete. And I am not doing a linear search. It is a _binary_ search...

Comment: @Moron: No, it's not the only characterization of NP-C (I'm assuming that's what you meant, not NP), but it is required. If a solution cannot be verified in polynomial time, it isn't NP-C.

Comment: @Adam: No I meant _NP_. You do know that NP-C = NP-Hard AND NP, right? Your objections were stated to imply it was NP-Hard but not in NP. That it is NP-Hard is easy to see by a reduction from SUBSET-SUM. The polynomial time verification is a characterization of _NP_, not NP-C. For example, maximum among an array of number. Easily verifiable in polynomial, but not NP-Complete (assuming P <> NP).

Comment: @Moron: I misread your comment; yes, NP-C = NP-Hard + NP. My original point was that--as far as I am aware, and correct me if I'm wrong--in order for a problem to be NP, its solution must be verifiable in polynomial time. While there are obviously other attributes about NP, I am operating under the assumption that this one is not optional.

Comment: @Adam: Nope. It is completely optional. As I said there are multiple characterizations, knapsack has the same issue, but it is in NP.  Of course, if we are being pedantic we should probably be talking about FNP, but as I said, the search version reduces to the decision version in P time (using binary search).

Comment: @Moron: Really? Well, that's news to me. I'm going to crawl back in my corporate hole how, where nobody else will know I'm wrong when I talk about P, NP, and NP-C! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Adam: It is true that for problems in NP for every input there is _some_ polynomial time verifiable certificate for that input (just consider an NDTM which accepts it, and consider one of the Yes paths+the TM as the 'certificate') In fact, that is why it is one of the _characterizations_ of NP (i.e. another equivalent definition). But, it is not the case that the 'solution' of _every_ algorithm _has_ to be a P time verifiable certificate. That is what I mean by optional: not every algorithm has to be a certificate producer. Of course, once converted to an NDTM, you can extract a certificate.

Comment: @Adam. So while you were not wrong in saying every NP problem has _some_ polynomial time verifiable certificate for every given input, IMO, you were applying it incorrectly. The 'solution' produced by an algorithm need not be the certificate. It could be something completely different. I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a [Knapsack-like problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Knapsack-like_problems), where the value of  your integers would be the "weight" of each item, the "profit" of each item is 1, and you are looking for the least number of items to exactly sum to the maximum allowable weight of the knapsack.

Comment: @Emon: The knapsack problem (when fractions are not allowed, as in your case) is not solvable in polynomial time. There is no general algorithm that is guaranteed to find the *best* solution using your criteria other than a brute-force search.

Comment: @Emon - As I commented above, it depends on the size of the input.  If it is small, I would suggest brute force.  Otherwise, I would look up solutions for the Subset Sum problem, which in general will give you a good solution, but not guarantee that it is the optimal solution.

Comment: Does knapsack allow negative weights?

Comment: @Moron: Traditionally, no. While negative weights would be allowable in the `0-1` version (meaning no duplicates), they would break any algorithm in the unbounded version, since you would want an infinite number of any negative-weight item.

Answer (score 0):

A simple-brute-force-method would be to read the text in, parse it into numbers, and then go through all combinations until you find the required sum.

A quicker solution would be to sort the numbers, then...
Add the largest number to your sum, Is it too big? if so, take it off and try the next smallest.
if the sum is too small, add the next largest number and repeat.
Continue adding numbers not letting the sum exceed the target. Finish when you hit the target.

Note that when you backtrack, you may need to back track more than one level. Sounds like a good case for recursion...

Comment: While the quick solution is guaranteed to find *a* series of numbers that is less than the target, it isn't guaranteed to find the *best* solution.

Comment: That is where the recursion comes i - perhaps I didn't explain myself well. It would find the closest solution that was lower than or equal to the target. It would also be easy to keep track of the "overflows" to also report the closest that is higher than the target. However it would not find the "best" if you determine the "best" to be the solution that uses the lowest number of values.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are large you can turn this into an Integer Programme. Using `Mathematica`s solver, it might look something like this

```
nums = {99, 20, 30 , 1, 100, 400, 5, 10};
vars = a /@ Range@Length@nums;
Minimize[(vars.nums - 183)^2, vars, Integers]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list of values, find the first value that's greater than the target, and start concentrating on the values that are less than the target.  Find the sum that's closest to the target without going over, then compare that to the first value greater than the target.  If the difference between the closest sum and the target is less than the difference between the first value greater than the target and the target, then you have the sum that's closest.

Kinda hokey, but I think the logic hangs together.